# Virtual Directory with struts-tiles

Tags: struts2, tiles

is have serious problems in configuring struts-tiles with virtual-directories for local developement. I have got my tiles-def.xml deployed in my ear. And i have got virtual-directory mapping, which works great, but not with tiles, because i want to include the jsp in my tiles-def.

is this possible? Does anybody have an experience?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would probably try using wildcards with your struts tiles results.

http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/wildcard-mappings.html

You may also need to include some configuration settings in your struts.xml:

```
<constant name="struts.enable.SlashesInActionNames" value="true"/>
<constant name="struts.mapper.alwaysSelectFullNamespace" value="false"/>
<constant name="struts.patternMatcher" value="regex" />
```

If you have access to the directory structure in the url or in the struts action class, it can be passed to the tiles results as follows:

```
//passing the value in with the action call
<action name="hello/{myDirectory}">
    <result type="tiles">/Hello.{1}.tiles</result>
</action>

//passing the value from a field within the action
<action name="hello">
    <result type="tiles">/Hello.${myDirectory}.tiles</result>
</action>
```

You then set up the tiles to accept wildcards as well

http://tiles.apache.org/framework/tutorial/advanced/wildcard.html

```
<definition name="hello.*.tiles" template="/layout.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/{1}/hello.jsp"/>
</definition>
```